# passing params to a different page

Tags: reactjs, parameters

Following code and params does not reach the target page. I can't understand why.

```js
<Link to={{ pathname: '/coursepage', state: { id: course._id } }}>. 
 {course._id}{course.topic}
</Link>
```

I worked with `useParams()` on the target page.

Any idea why that is?

Answer (score 0):

As per react-router v6 [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link#state) you should the `Link` component like following to pass the state:

```
<Link to="new-path" state={{ some: "value" }} />
```

so, your code becomes:

```
<Link to="/coursepage" state={{ id: course._id  }}>{course._id}{course.topic}</Link>
```

and access the state on the page like so:

```
let { state } = useLocation();
```